# jstl insert cannot be null and other issue

Tags: jstl

hello i am trying to insert some values to database using input filed and text area and a few selects but one problem keep showing. here is the code every thing is fine but the update statement is the issue i would like to point that the connection and scope of the tag is fine but any idea in this matter please i need it to keep going with the project

```
 <sql:update dataSource="${snapshot}" sql="insert into products (product_cat, product_brand, product_title,product_price ,product_desc ,product_image ,product_keywords) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)">
            <sql:param value="${param.product_title}" />
            <sql:param value="${param.product_cat}" />
            <sql:param value="${param.product_brand}" />
            <sql:param value="${param.product_image}" />
            <sql:param value="${param.product_price}" />
            <sql:param value="${param.product_desc}" />
            <sql:param value="${param.product_keywords}" />
     </sql:update>
     <jsp:forward page="list.jsp"></jsp:forward>
```

and this message keep showing

> Column 'product_title' cannot be null

also i followed few tutorial this one for sure was useful  [youtube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ge8TqXFtcXg)
but he removed this

```
(product_cat, product_brand, product_title,product_price ,product_desc ,product_image ,product_keywords)
```

Update:
i think the issue with the param tag so i posted the web file

this is my xml file to check the values i tried to look in the site all over but here is the web file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ROOT</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

the code is right and no need to change web.xml at all but the param are working with get action or it have to be adjusted also if the out tag and all the sql tag is working so param tag is working